# possible to have on screen elements rotate immediately

Tags: ios, swift, uiviewcontroller, uikit

When I rotate my device the red square on the middle of the screen moves to stay in the center of the screen regardless of rotation. However, when rotating the device, [the square does not immediately reposition itself, instead the previous location of the square can be seen until the rotation animation is fully complete.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VDnlk.jpg) Is their a way to have the square reposition itself immediately when the animation plays so that its old location is not seen during the rotation animation?

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {
    var square = UIView()

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        square.isHidden = true

        square = UIView(frame: CGRect(x: self.view.frame.width / 2 - 50, y: self.view.frame.height / 2 - 50, width: 100, height: 100))
        square.backgroundColor = UIColor.red
        self.view.addSubview(square)
        square.isHidden = false
    }

    override func didRotate(from fromInterfaceOrientation: UIInterfaceOrientation) {
        square.isHidden = true
        square = UIView(frame: CGRect(x: self.view.frame.width / 2 - 50, y: self.view.frame.height / 2 - 50, width: 100, height: 100))
        square.backgroundColor = UIColor.red
        self.view.addSubview(square)
        square.isHidden = false
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Two things:

1. `didRotate` was deprecated way back in iOS 8. It has been replaced by `viewWillTransition(to:with:)`.
2. Don't create a new square. Simply update the frame of the original square.

The code below creates one square and sets the `autoresizingMask` to keep it centered. No need to do anything else. Of course you could also setup constraints instead of the `autoresizingMask`.

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {
    var square: UIView!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        square = UIView(frame: CGRect(x: self.view.frame.width / 2 - 50, y: self.view.frame.height / 2 - 50, width: 100, height: 100))
        square.backgroundColor = UIColor.red
        square.autoresizingMask = [ .flexibleLeftMargin, .flexibleRightMargin, .flexibleTopMargin, .flexibleBottonMargin ]
        self.view.addSubview(square)
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you! This was very helpful